# Creating a Wind Chill Calculator and not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently working on a project in my Intro to Java class and I need to create a program that will ask the user for two numbers, calculate the wind chill and convert the temp to Celsius.

The outcome is supposed to look like this identically:

```
Ima Java Student
Project 2 – Wind-Chill Calculator

Enter the outside temperature (Fahrenheit) [-58 to 41]: 32
Enter the wind speed [2 to 50]: 10

Outside Temp (F)  Wind Speed  Wind-Chill (F)  Wind-Chill (C)
----------------  ----------  --------------  --------------
              32          10          23.727          -4.596
```

My output is just the following:

```
Ima Java Student
Project 2 – Wind-Chill Calculator
```

Here is my code in full. What am I missing here?!

```
/**
 * Author:  Dillon Carter
 * Course:  COP2551
 * Project#: 2
 * Title:   Wind Chill Calculator
 * Due Date: 7/9/2017
 *
 * Calculates the Wind Chill based on the outside Temperature and Wind Speed given by the user.
 * Then, converts the outcome from Fahrenheit to Celsius for the user.
*/

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {

     // Variable Declaration    
    int temperature = 0;
    int speed =  0;
    int windChill = 0;
    int celsius = 0;
    double windChill_C = 0;
    double windChill_F = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Ima Java Student");
    System.out.println("Project 2 - Wind-Chill Calculator");


    }




    // Gets input from user and saves as variables
    private boolean getInput() {



            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the outside temperature (Fahrenheit) [-58 to 41]:");
            int temperature = reader.nextInt();
            boolean isGoodTemp = (temperature >= -58 && temperature <= 41);

            System.out.println("Enter the wind speed [2 to 50]:");
            int windSpeed = reader.nextInt();
            boolean isGoodSpeed = (windSpeed >= 2 && windSpeed <= 50);
    return true;


    }

    // No clue what this is for....
    private void performCalculations(int temperature, int windSpeed) {

    }



    // Calculates the Wind Chill based on the temperature and wind speed given by the user
    private double calculateWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed) {

            windChill_F = 35.74 + 0.6215 *temperature - 35.75 * Math.pow(windSpeed, 0.16) + 0.4275*temperature * Math.pow(windSpeed, 0.16);
    return windChill_F;
    }


    // Converts temperature from Fharenheight to Celsius
    private double convertTemperature(double windChill_F) {

            windChill_C = Math.round((temperature - 32) * 5 / 9);
return windChill_C;



}
    // Displays the results to the user
    private void displayResults(int temperature, int windSpeed, double windChill_F, double windChill_C) {

            System.out.println( "Outside Temp (F)  " + "Wind Speed  " + "Wind-Chill (F)  "+ "Wind-Chill (C)  ");
            System.out.println( "---------------  " + "---------------  " + "---------------  " + "---------------  ");
            System.out.println( temperature + "  " + windSpeed + "  " + windChill_F + "  " + windChill_C);
        }    
    }
```

It's important to note that I am not allowed to create any more methods, but must used the methods included in my current code. I'm so close to making this work, I can feel it lol.

Comment: Well you don't actually call `getInput()` `performCalculations()` or `displayResults()` so I'm not sure what you expect to happen...

Comment: The main method is the only one that runs automatically.  The others have to be called if you want them to run.

Comment: You doesn't seem you need member variables, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this program. After temperature and speed were entered by user program calculates windChill and converts it to celcium. Finally results are displayed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    // Variable Declaration
    int temperature = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int windChill = 0;
    int celsius = 0;
    double windChill_C = 0;
    double windChill_F = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Ima Java Student");
        System.out.println("Project 2 - Wind-Chill Calculator");

        System.out.println();

        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        while (!calc.getInput()) {
            System.out.println("Temperature or wind speed is wrong. Try again");
        }
        calc.displayResults(calc.temperature, calc.speed, calc.windChill_F, calc.windChill_C);
    }

    // Gets input from user and saves as variables
    private boolean getInput() {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the outside temperature (Fahrenheit) [-58 to 41]:");
        temperature = reader.nextInt();
        boolean isGoodTemp = (temperature >= -58 && temperature <= 41);

        System.out.println("Enter the wind speed [2 to 50]:");
        speed = reader.nextInt();
        boolean isGoodSpeed = (speed >= 2 && speed <= 50);

        performCalculations(temperature, speed);
        return isGoodTemp && isGoodSpeed;
    }

    // No clue what this is for....
    private void performCalculations(int temperature, int windSpeed) {
        calculateWindChill(temperature, windSpeed);
        convertTemperature(windChill_F);
    }

    // Calculates the Wind Chill based on the temperature and wind speed given
    // by the user
    private double calculateWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed) {

        windChill_F = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.pow(windSpeed, 0.16)
                + 0.4275 * temperature * Math.pow(windSpeed, 0.16);
        return windChill_F;
    }

    // Converts temperature from Fharenheight to Celsius
    private double convertTemperature(double windChill_F) {

        windChill_C = Math.round((temperature - 32) * 5 / 9);
        return windChill_C;

    }

    // Displays the results to the user
    private void displayResults(int temperature, int windSpeed, double windChill_F, double windChill_C) {

        System.out.println("Outside Temp (F)  " + "Wind Speed  " + "Wind-Chill (F)  " + "Wind-Chill (C)  ");
        System.out.println("---------------  " + "---------------  " + "---------------  " + "---------------  ");
        System.out.println(temperature + "  " + windSpeed + "  " + windChill_F + "  " + windChill_C);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Ima Java Student
Project 2 - Wind-Chill Calculator

Enter the outside temperature (Fahrenheit) [-58 to 41]:
40
Enter the wind speed [2 to 50]:
24
Outside Temp (F)  Wind Speed  Wind-Chill (F)  Wind-Chill (C)  
---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  
40  24  29.58922393920365  4.0
```